# How to best and most efficiently Split files into vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file.readalllines

Say I have a 5 GB file. I want to split it in the following way.

First 100 MB is on the file

The rest go some reserve file

I do not want to use readalllines kind of function because it's too slow for large files.

I do not want to read the whole file to the memory. I want the program to handle only a medium chunk of data at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes.aspx) class and its method to read file in chunks.

```
Dim chunk() As Byte
chunk = br.ReadBytes(1024)
```

Comment: cool. What about if we want to make sure that a new line separates the files?